# Como fusionar 3 array de objetos en uno solo

Tags: javascript, funciones, vanilla

Tengo 3 array de objetos que necesito fusionar en uno solo para recorrerlo y obtener un resultado.

Este es son mis variables:

```
const arra1 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Gold"); // esta es la funcion que hice par obtener el siguiente resultado 

// Esto es el resultado de lo que tiene cada uno adentro 
   [{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1},
   {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64}]

const array2 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Silver");
 // Esto es el resultado de lo que tiene cada uno adentro 
       [{team: 'FRA', medal: 'Silver', total: 55},
       {team: 'RUS', medal: 'Silver', total: 28}]

    const arra3 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Bronze"); 
 // Esto es el resultado de lo que tiene cada uno adentro 
       [{team: 'ITA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24},
       {team: 'ESP', medal: 'Bronze', total: 17}]
```

y necesito obtener esto:

```
const array1 = Fusion de todas las medallas

//con este resultado 
[{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1},
{team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64},
{team: 'FRA', medal: 'Silver', total: 55},
{team: 'RUS', medal: 'Silver', total: 28}
{team: 'ITA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24},
{team: 'ESP', medal: 'Bronze', total: 17}]
```

probe con el metodo concat y no me funciono;

Hice algo así:

`arra1 = arra1.concat(arra2,arra3);`
obtuve este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')

Soy nueva en esto y de verdad que se me ha hecho dificil entenderlo, sólo puedo usar Vanilla Javascript para resolverlo, si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco.

Comment: la solución es sencilla, solo debes declarar una nueva variable , algo así:
`const array4 = arra1.concat(array2, arra3);`. Y fíjate bien como escribes tus variables, algunas dicen `arra` y otras `array`.

Comment: Gracias jhon,, si escribi mal las variables todas son arra1, arra2, arra3, pero aplique tu solucion y no me resulto me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si potencialmente vas a usar más arrays, creo que lo mejor sería almacenarlos en un solo array y usar [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const arra1 = [{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1}, {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64}]
const arra2 = [{team: 'FRA', medal: 'Silver', total: 55}, {team: 'RUS', medal: 'Silver', total: 28}]
const arra3 = [{team: 'ITA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24}, {team: 'ESP', medal: 'Bronze', total: 17}]

const finalRes = [arra1, arra2, arra3].flat()
console.log(finalRes);
```

La magia está en que el prototipo `flat()` nos convierte un array de arrays a uno solo, es decir que elimina los arrays anidados y pone sus elementos en el array principal

---

Por otro lado, si usas solo esos arrays, puedes usar [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
const arra1 = [{team: 'JOR', medal: 'Gold', total: 1}, {team: 'GBR', medal: 'Gold', total: 64}]
const arra2 = [{team: 'FRA', medal: 'Silver', total: 55}, {team: 'RUS', medal: 'Silver', total: 28}]
const arra3 = [{team: 'ITA', medal: 'Bronze', total: 24}, {team: 'ESP', medal: 'Bronze', total: 17}]

const finalRes = arra1.concat(arra2, arra3);
console.log(finalRes);
```

---

Por lo que he leido, obtienes un error como el siguiente

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')
```

Revisa tu función, debe devolver un array, para probar que sí devuelve un array puedes imprimir `arra1`, `array2` y `arra3` antes de ejecutar el método para obtener el resultado que deseas, algo como

```js
const arra1 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Gold");
const arra2 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Silver");
const arra3 = computeData(datos.athletes,"Bronze");

console.log(arra1, arra2, arra3);

// Consulta la consola de la página para ver qué obtuviste
// ...
```